# Inject hibernate PersistenceUnit

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

By using CDI as shown in the next code:

```
@PersistenceUnit
EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

I want to inject my hibernate `EntityManagerFactory`

Currently if I execute the next line:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HibernatePersistanceProv");
```

It works just as expected, but if I do it using the first method it tries to use the Derby connection I know this because I get the next error message:

`org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection`

By the stack trace I know that it is caused because of this.

`Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with message Connection refused.`

Which I know it is because it is trying to connect to the (Java DB) Derby db.

My persistance.xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="HibernatePersistanceProv" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aschema"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aschema"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I was reading that apparently I need to specify a `standalone.xml` to provide a different `<jta-data-source>` but it seams to me a bit more complicated than what it should be (I do not want to chase the wrong rabbit), I have been from the Java EE world for a while so I consider my self as brand new to this (*for dummies* explanations are widely appreciated).

(If it helps) I am running on a GlassFish 4.1 server. Please ask if any other information is required.

Comment: "*I was reading that apparently I need to specify a `standalone.xml` to provide a different `<jta-data-source>`.*" `standalone.xml` is a JBoss / WildFly specific configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution end up being that I was not managing properly my connections pools in Glassfish, in order to achieve this behavior (at least this is the way I found, but I am pretty sure they should be more) you need to:

**Glassfish side:**

1. In the *"Common Tasks"* Panel (left side of the administrator console (Glasfish4) expand **JDBC**.
2. Select **JDBC Connection Pools** and click the *New* button on top of the main (central) panel, proceed to configure the data base connection for the pool.
3. Now in the same **JDBC** section previously mentioned (left panel) select **JDBC Resources** (should be immediately above **JDBC Connection Pools**) there you can create a new resource so that you can use the *CDI* using the name of your choice OR as I did, just configure it in the **jdbc/__default** connection (as you may imagine that is the default connection provided by Glassfish *CDI* name space, to select your connection pool click on the link **jdbc/__default** on the table which appeared on the main (central) panel, that will take you into another form where you could use the drop down labeled as **Pool Name:** to select your newly configured connection pool, or the one of your choice; save it, top left of the main (central) panel.

**Hibernate side:**

1. In the `persistence.xml`, you can either:
   a) Be sure that you are not providing any `<jta-data-source>` (**IFF** you configured in the **jdbc/__default**)
   b) Provide the **JNDI Name** (usually the name you provided for your **JDBC Resources** (in case you created one) or in the case of the default connection (**jdbc/__default**) you can see the JDNI name in the edit view (which is: java:comp/DefaultDataSource).
   Write that into `<jta-data-source>` in your persistence.xml and it should do the trick.

Sorry for the lack of graphical resources, I'll try to add them later. I hope it works for you *"anonymous reader"*.

**IMPORTANT NOTE** I needed to switch back to Glassfish 4 (not 4.1) because Glassfish 4.1 currently (As of Jan `16) has a bug which does not allows you to create new connection pools.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is database related but for injecting EntityManager I usually go with this:

```
public class EntityManagerFactoryProducer {

        @Produces
        @ApplicationScoped
        public EntityManagerFactory create() {
            return Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("HibernatePersistanceProv");
        }

        public void destroy(@Disposes EntityManagerFactory factory) {
            factory.close();
        }

    }

    public class EntityManagerProducer {

        @Inject
        private EntityManagerFactory emf;

        @Produces
        @RequestScoped
        public EntityManager create() {
            return emf.createEntityManager();
        }

        public void destroy(@Disposes EntityManager em) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

Than just simply inject it where ever you want. If you have more database use qualifier combined with inject.

```
@Inject
private EntityManager entityManager;
```